# How long does a context switch take in Linux?

Tags: linux, performance, multithreading, low-level

I'm curious how many cycles it takes to change contexts in Linux.  I'm specifically using an E5405 Xeon (x64), but I'd love to see how it compares to other platforms as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There`s a free app called LMBench written by Larry McVoy and friends. It provides a bunch of OS & HW benchmarks
One of the tests is called lat_ctx and it measures contex switch latencies.
Google for lmbench and check for yourself on your own HW. Its the only way to get a number meaningful to you.

Gilad

Comment: Readers should note that LMBench requires BitKeeper, which is non-free software to be installed.

Comment: @ShantanuKumar that is simply not true: http://www.bitmover.com/lmbench/get_lmbench.html

Comment: When I tried running LMBench I kept running into the error
"make[1]: Entering directory `/home/shantanu/app/src/lmbench3/src'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `../SCCS/s.ChangeSet', needed by `bk.ver'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/shantanu/app/src/lmbench3/src'
make: *** [lmbench] Error 2"
which led to me think so.

Comment: The people that wrote LMbench are the same people that many years later created BitKeeper, but this is just a build failure, not a a dependency on BitKeeper.

Comment: I stand corrected. However, I am yet to have LMBench working. If somebody has a clue please pass it on to me.

Comment: @Shantanu Kumar - You probably worked it out by now, but you can just use touch to create the "missing" file and code will build

Answer (score 3):

Run **vmstat** on your machine while doing something that requires heavy context switching. It doesnt tell you how long the actual switch takes, but it will tell you how many switches you do per second.

Then, you have to estimate how much each timeslice spends performing actual code, compared to switching context. Maybe a 100:1 or something? I dont know. 1000:1?

A machine of mine is now doing roughly 3000 switches per second, ie 0.3 ms per timeslice. With a ratio of 100:1 that would mean the actual switch takes 0.003 ms.

But, with multiple cores, threads yielding execution, etc etc, I'm wouldnt draw any conclusion from such a guess :)

Answer (score -1):

I've written code that's able to echo (small) UDP packets at 200k packets per second.

That suggests that it's possible to context switch in not more than 2.5 microseconds, with the actual context switch probably taking somewhat less than that.

Comment: Are you sure you are switching context and not get several UDP packets from the OS in one go?