# How to add extra tasks to a running multiprocessing pool, based on worker results?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Say I have a set of 20 CPU heavy tasks (~1 hour each, but some take a lot longer) that are run by calling a function via e.g. `Pool.apply_async(function, task_list)` etc. PC has 12 Cores. So I can spread the load, and use all 12 cores.

The result of each task could require that a new task has to be run (some task might need 1 new run, others maybe 10).

When a new task is required, I would like to spawn that task into the existing pool `task_list`, to fully optimize CPU usage at all time.

Currently I run the 20 tasks, wait to finish, start the new ~18 tasks, wait to finish, start the remaining new tasks, ...., while it happens only 1 core is being used for an hour, instead of 12. This adds up to a loss of several hours to days in calculation time. I could run the updated task in the same worker, however this results in an even larger loss)

With pool it does not seem possible to add more tasks to the pool while it is started. Is that correct, or are there some smart ways to do this that I missed while searching all over the place?

(Only option I see is to use `process` instead of `pool`, and make a while loop over a dynamic list that starts a typical task as a single process, while only allowing up to 12 processes running at the same time, and for each task, or new task, put them in the dynamic list, and remove the task when it is send to a process.)

Comment: `apply_async` is for single function call jobs and is using one process, did you mean `map_async`? You can send new jobs into an existing pool _before_ all tasks are finished with an async-method. They also offer registering callback functions when the result is ready. Easier for your case would be to just put everything what it needs to complete the task into one function (skipping the resubmitting of another task) and use `pool.map` with `chunksize=1`. Highly relevant background to Pool's chunksize you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54032744/9059420).

Comment: thanks, should indeed be a map option, and chunksize needs definitely be 1. Keeping the task in the same function creates the risk of that the last started worker function runs for 10 hours, while the others are idle.

Your suggestion the task_list can be increased combined with the answer by @asafpr helped me understand the 'Queue()' feature, so currently my guess is when I use the task_list as a Queue for the 'args' in the pool, and add tasks to it should work. Found an example that worked using 'Process' instead of 'Pool' I will update and clean later on this weekend hopefully.

Comment: Python help also suggests this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes (first example when opening link)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Queue, you can see an example here:
https://www.journaldev.com/15631/python-multiprocessing-example
This way you'll be able to add to the Queue and have a constant number of runners taking from the Queue.

Comment: Please post the relevant code, and not just a link.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

# Execute your task here
def task(s):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print(s, 'Task Start')
    if len(s) > 2:
        return s, []
    
    time.sleep(0.1)

    # "/" will become ["/0", "/1"]
    # "/0" will become ["/00", "/01"]
    # and so on
    l = [s + str(i) for i in range(2)]
    
    print(s, 'Task End')
    return s, l

with multiprocessing.Pool(16) as p:
    async_result_list = []
    
    # This function will be executed in main process
    # but in a seperated thread, after the task is done
    def callback(args):
        s, l = args
        print(s, 'Callback Start')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        # Add to
        # 1. pool, so it will be executed in the multiprocessing pool
        # 2. async_result_list, so its result can be waited
        for t in l:
            print(t, 'Task Submit')
            async_result_list.append(p.apply_async(task, args=[t], callback=callback))
        print(s, 'Callback End')

    # Thee first initial task
    print('/', 'Task Submit')
    async_result_list.append(p.apply_async(task, args=['/'], callback=callback))

    result_list = []
    while len(async_result_list) > 0:
        async_result = async_result_list[0]
        # t.get will block until the task and the callback is done
        # so you needn't worry the program quite after all tasks are submitted
        s, l = async_result.get()
        result_list.append(l)
        print(s, 'Get Result')
        async_result_list.pop(0)


print(result_list)
```

Some explanation:

- Submit the initial task to the pool by `async_apply`
- When a task is finished, `callback` function will be invoked, add more tasks based on its result in `callback` function.
- Every time a task is submitted, add it to `async_result_list`, so you can wait for it
- After the first submission, constantly exam the `async_result_list`, when a result is retrieved, push it to `result_list`, and pop it from `async_result_list`
- Because the result is retrievable only after the callback function is finished, there's no need to worry the process finished before all tasks are submitted

Here's the ouptut of the demo:

```
/ Task Submit
/ Task Start
/ Task End
/ Callback Start
/0 Task Submit
/1 Task Submit
/ Callback End
/ Get Result
/0 Task Start
/1 Task Start
/1 Task End
/0 Task End
/0 Callback Start
/00 Task Submit
/01 Task Submit
/0 Callback End
/0 Get Result
/1 Callback Start
/00 Task Start
/01 Task Start
/10 Task Submit
/11 Task Submit
/1 Callback End
/1 Get Result
/00 Callback Start
/10 Task Start
/11 Task Start
/00 Callback End
/01 Callback Start
/00 Get Result
/01 Callback End
/10 Callback Start
/01 Get Result
/10 Callback End
/11 Callback Start
/10 Get Result
/11 Callback End
/11 Get Result
[['/0', '/1'], ['/00', '/01'], ['/10', '/11'], [], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

# pool size is 3, so three executions of Function is happening in
# parallel.
# When one of the function processing finishes, 
# it picks the next argument and so on.

def function(x):
    exec(x)

args = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.....]

pl = Pool(3)
jobs = pl.map(function, [ list of args for function ])
for job in jobs:
    print("process.returncode:", job.returncode, job.args)
```