# Simulating concurrent clients with multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, python-multiprocessing, redis-py

I have framework which communicates with the server over redis. I want to test it and therefore I wanted to send numerous requests at the same time (to simulate concurrent clients sending reqs to server at once). I know that I should use **multiprocessing** but one thing is not clear to me. Here is what I have:

```
def func(x):
client = rpcpyredis.Proxy("EchoService")
print(client.echo("test"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  processes = []
  start = time.time()
  p_pool = Pool(4)
  p_results = p_pool.map(func, range(300))
  p_pool.close()
  p_pool.join()
  print(time.time() - start)
```

I am confused with the number of **processess**. Does calling the function this way means, that I have maximum of 4 concurrent clients at any moment of time, or does it mean that I have 300 concurrent clients (scheduled over 4 processes)?

```
client = rpcpyredis.Proxy("EchoService")
```

represents client object i.e. connection to Redis instance

Comment: Please always include your imports in your code here.

Comment: You have four parallel workers and up to four clients at any moment of time here. Might help you understand: [Python multiprocessing: understanding logic behind chunksize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53751050/9059420)