# Multiprocessing a python for loop and saving results as a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am attempting to speed up some python code can only run single threaded. I an running many of these in a for loop and would like to parallelize it and save the results in a dictionary.

I've searched stack overflow and read the `multiprocessing` documentation but can't find a good solution.

Example of not parallelized:

```
%%time
# This only uses one thread! It's slow
mydict = {}
for i in range(20000000):
    mydict[i] = i**2
```

Returns:

```
CPU times: user 8.13 s, sys: 1.04 s, total: 9.17 s
Wall time: 9.21 s
```

and my dictionary is correct

```
print([mydict[i] for i in range(10)])
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

My attempt at parallelizing:

```
%%time
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
def square(d, i):
    d[i] = i**2

with mp.Manager() as manager:
    d = manager.dict()
    with manager.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        pool.map(square, (d, range(20000000)))
```

Returns:

```
TypeError: square() missing 1 required positional argument: 'i'
```

Expected results are the correct dictionary but the time being roughly 1/4 of 9.21s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have a target function with multiple parameters, you need `pool.starmap()`. `.starmap()` will unpack and map the argument-tuples in your `iterable` to the parameters of your target function.
The `iterable`-parameter needs this layout for use with `.starmap()`:

```
iterable = [(argA1, argB1), (argA2, argB2) ...]
```

Use `itertools.repeat()` to replicate the references for scalars like your `d` and create the iterable of argument-tuples with `zip()`:

```
pool.starmap(square, zip(itertools.repeat(d), range(20)))
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. However in my example this ended up taking much longer to process than just a single thread. Hopefully it will improve the speed when I use it in the actual application. Very helpful to know abou the `starmap` function though!

Comment: @Rob You're welcome! Yeah, there's no guarantee that multiprocessing will always be faster because of the overhead involved. When you look at the pictures in chapter 8 of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54813527/9059420) you can get the idea how overhead (and chunking) can influence timings.