# Weird behaviour with multiprocessing Pool.map

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I observe a really weird behaviour when using `pool.map` to call a method function.
With only one process the behaviour is not the same as a simple for loop and we enter several times in the `if not self.seeded:` block whereas we should not.
Here is the codes and outputs below :

```py
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool


class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.seeded = False
        print("Constructor of MyClass called")

    def f(self, i):
        print("f called with", i)
        if not self.seeded:
            print("PID : {}, id(self.seeded) : {}, self.seeded : {}".format(os.getpid(), id(self.seeded), self.seeded))
            self.seeded = True

    def multi_call_pool_map(self):
        with Pool(processes=1) as pool:
            print("multi_call_pool_map with {} processes...".format(pool._processes))
            pool.map(self.f, range(10))

    def multi_call_for_loop(self):
        print("multi_call_for_loop ...")
        list_res = []
        for i in range(10):
            list_res.append(self.f(i))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyClass().multi_call_pool_map()
```

outputs :

```
Constructor of MyClass called
multi_call_pool_map with 1 processes...
f called with 0
PID : 18248, id(self.seeded) : 1864747472, self.seeded : False
f called with 1
f called with 2
f called with 3
PID : 18248, id(self.seeded) : 1864747472, self.seeded : False
f called with 4
f called with 5
f called with 6
PID : 18248, id(self.seeded) : 1864747472, self.seeded : False
f called with 7
f called with 8
f called with 9
PID : 18248, id(self.seeded) : 1864747472, self.seeded : False
```

And with the for loop :

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyClass().multi_call_for_loop()
```

outputs :

```
Constructor of MyClass called
multi_call_for_loop ...
f called with 0
PID : 15840, id(self.seeded) : 1864747472, self.seeded : False
f called with 1
f called with 2
f called with 3
f called with 4
f called with 5
f called with 6
f called with 7
f called with 8
f called with 9
```

How can we explain the behaviour with pool.map (first case) ? I don't understand why we enter multiple times inside the if block because `self.seeded` is set to `False`  only in the constructor and the constructor is called only once...
(I have Python 3.6.8)

Comment: It's because of the way Pool is chunking your input iterable. The chunksize for your setup will be 3, resulting in [3,3,3,1] chunks here. You can calculate it with `calc_chunksize()` in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53751050/9059420).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when running the code and also printing `self` inside `f`, we can see that before each time we enter the `if` clause, the instance actually changes:

```py
    def f(self, i):
        print("f called with", i, "self is",self)
        if not self.seeded:
            print("PID : {}, id(self.seeded) : {}, self.seeded : {}".format(os.getpid(), id(self.seeded), self.seeded))
            self.seeded = True
```

this outputs:

```
Constructor of MyClass called
multi_call_pool_map with 1 processes...
f called with 0 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f30cd592b38>
PID : 22879, id(self.seeded) : 10744096, self.seeded : False
f called with 1 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f30cd592b38>
f called with 2 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f30cd592b38>
f called with 3 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f30cd592b00>
PID : 22879, id(self.seeded) : 10744096, self.seeded : False
f called with 4 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f30cd592b00>
f called with 5 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f30cd592b00>
f called with 6 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f30cd592ac8>
PID : 22879, id(self.seeded) : 10744096, self.seeded : False
f called with 7 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f30cd592ac8>
f called with 8 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f30cd592ac8>
f called with 9 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f30cd592a90>
PID : 22879, id(self.seeded) : 10744096, self.seeded : False
```

if you add `chunksize=10` to `.map()` it will behave just like the for loop:

```py
    def multi_call_pool_map(self):
        with Pool(processes=1) as pool:
            print("multi_call_pool_map with {} processes...".format(pool._processes))
            pool.map(self.f, range(10), chunksize=10)
```

this outputs:

```
Constructor of MyClass called
multi_call_pool_map with 1 processes...
f called with 0 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7fd175093b00>
PID : 22972, id(self.seeded) : 10744096, self.seeded : False
f called with 1 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7fd175093b00>
f called with 2 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7fd175093b00>
f called with 3 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7fd175093b00>
f called with 4 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7fd175093b00>
f called with 5 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7fd175093b00>
f called with 6 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7fd175093b00>
f called with 7 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7fd175093b00>
f called with 8 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7fd175093b00>
f called with 9 self is <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7fd175093b00>
```

exactly why this happens is a very elaborate implementation detail and has to do with how `multiprocessing` shares data between processes in the same pool.

I'm afraid I'm not qualified enough to answer exactly how and why this works internally.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The fact that the constructor is called only once despite having several instances is a bit confusing. And why id(self.seeded) is the same for all the different instances ?

Comment: I'm trying to find a simple article about this online, but all I find is regarding the usage and not internal details I'm afraid

Comment: It depends what you want to do, but using ```from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool``` (which is NOT the same! Google multiprocessing vs multithreading) you immediately get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

When you use an instance method with `Pool.map`, a copy of the object instance is sent to the worker process with help of the `pickle` module. Your results show how `map` works in chunks, and that the object instance is reloaded from the pickled form at start of each chunk. Loading a pickle does not call `__init__`.

See https://thelaziestprogrammer.com/python/a-multiprocessing-pool-pickle for more explanation what goes on under the hood.