# Are results of multiprocessing.Pool.map_async() returned in the same order of the input?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, process-pool

Reading [multiprocessing.Pool doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) I understood that `map_async` and `apply_async` are two versions of `map` and `appy` that are supposed to be faster, but that do not guarantee that the inputs are processed in the same order as they are provided.

However, I do not understand if, when calling `multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.get()` are the results "reordered" to match the input order, or are they returned in the order they were processed?

Comment: I know by experience that the result is ordered, and the documentation suggests it, but surprisingly enough, this isn't explicitly mentioned.

Comment: It is explicitly mentioned that `imap_unordered` is (shocker) ordered, so it could be a case of assumed ordered unless stated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, return-order will be the same as input-order. The only difference is that the async-methods do not block the `MainThread` in the parent and you will have to `.get()` the result explicitly. `.map()` and `.map_async()` both call the same low-level method `._map_async()` under the hood.

Note that **order of processing** and **return-order** are two different things. Processing order is not guaranteed and influenced by [chunking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53751050/9059420).

For `.apply_async()` you will get the result for which specific `AsyncResult`-object you are calling `.get()` upon.

Answer (score 0):

Performing the test below it seems that the order is restored when calling `get()`. As [Right Leg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7051394/right-leg) said, however, I cannot find any mention to it in the doc. Therefore I won't accept this answer until this is not proved by a fact, rather than a test

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import sleep

def func(i):
    if i == 1:
        sleep(3)
    return i**2



if __name__=='__main__':

    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        res = pool.map_async(func, range(10)).get()
        print(res)
```