# More processes than multiprocess pool size, when do the extra processes run?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

Say I have a pool of size 5 and a worker that I want to call 10 times. Lets say the worker is very cpu intensive and takes on order of minutes to complete its task.

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)
for i in range(10):
    pool.apply_async(pool_worker)
```

After the 5th iteration, the pool is filled up. What happens to the rest of the worker calls? Are they queued up until the previous workers are done?

Comment: While not directly related to your question, this comprehensive answer should be of interest and relevance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54032744/5437918

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs aren't very explicit about this. In general: Once a process is finished and freed it catches the next available task (therefore: queued up). If you try

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep

def sleeping(i):
    print(f"{i} started")
    sleep(5)
    print(f"{i} ended")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(processes=5) as p:
        results = [p.apply_async(sleeping, args=(i,)) for i in range(10)]
        results = [result.get() for result in results]
```

then you'll get a result like

```
0 started
1 started
2 started
3 started
4 started
3 ended
0 ended
5 started
6 started
1 ended
7 started
2 ended
8 started
4 ended
9 started
5 ended
6 ended
7 ended
8 ended
9 ended
```

Depending on the framework it could also be that once a process has finished its workload, it is terminated, a new one started instead, and then the next availabe task taken over by the new process. [From the docs:](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)

> **Note** Worker processes within a Pool typically live for the complete duration of the Pool’s work queue. A frequent pattern found in other systems (such as Apache, mod_wsgi, etc) to free resources held by workers is to allow a worker within a pool to complete only a set amount of work before being exiting, being cleaned up and a new process spawned to replace the old one. The maxtasksperchild argument to the Pool exposes this ability to the end user.