# Polars apply performance for custom functions

Tags: pandas, apply, python-polars

I've enjoyed with Polars significant speed-ups over Pandas, except one case. I'm newbie to Polars, so it could be just my wrong usage. Anyway here is the toy-example:
on single column I need to apply custom function in my case it is `parse` from `probablypeople` library (https://github.com/datamade/probablepeople) but problem is generic.

Plain pandas `apply` has similar runtime like Polars, but pandas with `parallel_apply` from (https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel) gets speed-up proportional to number of cores.

It looks for me that Polars uses only single core for custom functions,or I miss something?

If I use Polars correctly, maybe there is a possibility to create tool like `pandaralell` for Polars?

```
!pip install probablepeople
!pip install pandarallel

import pandas as pd
import probablepeople as pp
import polars as pl
from pandarallel import pandarallel

AMOUNT = 1000_000
#Pandas:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ["Mr. Joe Smith"]})
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(AMOUNT)].reset_index(drop=True)

df['b'] = df['a'].apply(pp.parse)

#Pandarallel:
pandarallel.initialize(progress_bar=True)
df['b_multi'] = df['a'].parallel_apply(pp.parse)

#Polars:
dfp = pl.DataFrame({'a': ["Mr. Joe Smith"]})
dfp = dfp.select(pl.all().repeat_by(AMOUNT).explode())

dfp = dfp.with_columns(pl.col('a').apply(pp.parse).alias('b'))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pandarallel` uses multiprocessing.

You could also [use multiprocessing with polars.](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/misc/multiprocessing/)

We're using [multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) with the default settings as an example.

- [multiprocessing: Understanding logic behind `chunksize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751050/multiprocessing-understanding-logic-behind-chunksize)

```py
import multiprocessing
import polars as pl
import probablepeople as pp
from   pip._vendor.rich.progress import track

def parallel_apply(function, column):
    with multiprocessing.get_context("spawn").Pool() as pool:
        return pl.Series(pool.imap(function, track(column)))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    df = pl.DataFrame({
       "name": ["Mr. Joe Smith", "Mrs. I & II Alice Random"]
    })

    df = df.with_columns(pp = 
       pl.col("name").map_batches(lambda col: parallel_apply(pp.parse, col))
    )

    print(df)
```

- [`.map_batches()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_batches.html#polars.Expr.map_batches) is used to pass the full column to a function.
- The column is passed to `parallel_apply` along with the Python function to be executed in the Pool e.g. `pp.parse`
- [`rich.progress.track()`](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/progress.html#rich.progress.track) (which also comes bundled with `pip`) is used for a progress bar.

```
Working... ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 100% 0:00:00
shape: (2, 2)
┌──────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ name                     ┆ pp                                │
│ ---                      ┆ ---                               │
│ str                      ┆ list[list[str]]                   │
╞══════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ Mr. Joe Smith            ┆ [["Mr.", "PrefixMarital"], ["Joe… │
│ Mrs. I & II Alice Random ┆ [["Mrs.", "PrefixMarital"], ["I"… │
└──────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

---

#### Performance

Just as a basic comparison, creating a `1_000_000` row dataframe - I get the following runtimes:

| multiprocessing | duration |
| --- | --- |
| yes | 1m23s |
| no | 5m2s |

Comment: Could you please further explain the phrase "We're using multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap with the default settings as an example."? **Does Polars.Expr.map_bathces()** use multi-processing by default? Thanks!

Comment: @KevinLi It means the default value for imap's chunksize. Choosing an optimal chunksize is a rather complex topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751050/multiprocessing-understanding-logic-behind-chunksize - `.map_batches` does not use multiprocessing by default - which is the reason for the approach shown here.