# How can I improve the runtime of row-wise operations in Polars?

Tags: multiprocessing, apply, python-polars

We are looking to switch to Polars as our main data processing framework from DataFlow + mostly numpy. However some of transformation we apply atm are row-wise and can't be vectorised in neither numpy nor polars expressions.

Seems like the way to go here is to call `map_elements`, former `apply`, and transfer polars list/array into numpy to pass it into python function. This seems to be extremely slow, probably for two reasons:

1. data transfer is happening
2. polars use only one core

I know that all data frameworks suggest to not use `apply` until it is really required and we have exactly such case here. The question is - what can we do to go beyond expectations :)?

VAEX seems to be [claiming](https://vaex.io/docs/tutorial.html#The-escape-hatch:-apply) to be using multiprocessing when apply is called. There seems to be no such thing in Polars.  [Multiprocessing page in Polars User guide](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/misc/multiprocessing/) has a very basic example where the same frame is passed into spawned process and processed output is not returned back to main. While it seems like serialisation/deserialisation (I tried to arrow) to be taking too much time.

The question is how Polars users can improve applying `map_elements`? Maybe there are some recent developments here, not yet documented ? Is there some recommendations on how users can efficiently pass data frame slices to and from child processes?

Thank you.

**UPDT: thanks to @jqurious hint**

we managed to apply multiprocessing for row-wise operations:

```
def parallel_apply(func, iterable, chunksize=1):
    python_iterable = list(iterable.to_numpy())
    with multiprocessing.get_context("spawn").Pool(processes=processes) as pool:
        result = pool.imap(func, track(python_iterable), chunksize)
        return pl.Series(result)
```

few lessons learned:

- `to_numpy()` is an order of magnitude faster than `to_list()` which seems to be called when iterating over polars series. converting to python iterable saved us 40% of runtime
- smaller chunk size worked better for us, however this might be related to huge numpy matrices we have in every row
- to_numpy() converts series of list to array of arrays (as those arrays might be of variable size). thus some post processing might be required - like stacking

Comment: I voted to close as too broad. That said, depending on the problem, you can use numba to make vectorized ufuncs. You can make regular python udf that return a series with map_batches. Those functions can use parallelism internally (I think, never tried).

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you can show exactly what your Python function is doing? You can write custom functions in Rust. The Polars Plugin API is new, the docs are about to be added: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/44a571ba9dc7e2a9e74807be2399ae7507aaf756/docs/user-guide/expressions/plugins.md - https://github.com/MarcoGorelli/polars-business is an example plugin that implements business day operations.

Comment: @jqurious the python function is an entry point to a python package written by other teams outside of our control. unfortunately we don't have the option to aski them to rewrite the package in polars expressions. the entrypoint expects a single polars-row input and return some python primitive types. In DataFlow this is not a problem since Beam's single pcollection is a like a Polars single row.

Comment: Ah okay, so the calling of a Python function is actually required. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74749075/19355181 may be a useful example, it runs each row through a python function using multiprocessing.

Comment: Hm ok, that answer is a bit old so it needs some syntax updates. The basic idea is instead of running `.map_elements` directly, you pass the whole column to a function with `.map_batches` and inside that function you create your Pool to run the external Python function.

Comment: Very useful information in your "lessons learned". Perhaps it's worth adding as an answer (maybe you have a better name than `parallel_apply`, mentioning "multiprocessing" in the question title could also help). I changed chunksize due to https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap *"For very long iterables using a large value for chunksize can make the job complete much faster than using the default value of 1."* I think it's best if I remove it and link to the docs instead based on your results. Thanks for the updates.

Comment: I agree with @jqurious's point to move your lessons learned to an answer. Answering one's own questions is definitely allowed so long as you're not asking questions for the sole purpose of answering them yourself.